# Change subversion username in NetBeans 6.9.1

Tags: netbeans-6.9

Am using NetBeans 6.9.1

I need to change the username and password for URL repository (am working on many repositories) to my project after i entered the username the first time i checked out from repository , How can i do that .

I checked from menu team-->subversion options and cant find any thing helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to`Tools > Options > Misc > Versioning > Subversion`,

click on 
`Manage Connections`, select the `Repository Url` for the repository from the combo box 
and update the credentials. Am using NetBeans 6.9.1

[netbeans how to modify uers name http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/4500/changesvnusername.png](http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/4500/changesvnusername.png)